# Shift logo on page left/right

Tags: pdftex, wallpaper

I am trying to insert my company logo on the corners of the pages. I used

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}  % note the x at the end
    \usepackage{graphicx} %%Zum Laden von Grafiken
    \usepackage{wallpaper}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \pagestyle{empty} 
    \begin{document}
    \pagestyle{plain} 
    \ThisULCornerWallPaper{0.20}{logo.png}
    \lipsum[2-4]
    \end{document}
```

It works. But I want to shift it, e.g. 5 pts to left/right. How can I do it?

Comment: the answer below uses tikz for placement since certain wallpaper commands do not entertain `\addtolength{\wpXoffset}{8cm}` and 
`\addtolength{\wpYoffset}{12cm}` for positioning -- image A is with wallpaper and image B is with tikz -- the `$(current page.north west) + (5cm,-1cm) $` will calculate the position -- instead of cm one can use pts or em dimension also

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} 

\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pagestyle{empty} 
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{plain} 
    \ThisULCornerWallPaper{0.20}{example-image-a}
    \lipsum[2-4]
    
    \tikz[remember picture, overlay]\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] 
    at ($(current page.north west) + (5cm,-1cm) $) {\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-b}}; 
\end{document}
```